# Xcode Unit Testing, wait in `class setUp()`

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing

I'm currently adding a lot of unit tests in my app, to check if WS are in a running state.

I know perfectly how to wait inside a testMethod, using `expectations`.

What I want is less common. I have a test case working on user favorites data. To be sure of the state of this user, I want to create a fully new user before the case ( and not before each test )

So I want to use

```
public class func setUp() {
  //call here WS ( async call )
}
```

My issue is, as I am in a `class` func, I cannot use `expectation` and `waitForExpectation` because these are instance methods.

Does anybody as an idea on how to wait for my WS complete before executing the tests ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use semaphore technique to accomplish what you want.

```
        let fakeWSCallProcessingTimeInSeconds = 2.0
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(fakeWSCallProcessingTimeInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }
        let timeoutInNanoSeconds = 5 * 1000000000
        let timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(timeoutInNanoSeconds))
        if dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, timeout) != 0 {
            XCTFail("WS operation timed out")
        }
```

This code will fake a webservice call with 2 seconds delay (dispatch_after) which in your case should be replaced with the actual call. Once the call is done and your user object is set up, you use "dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)" to free up the semaphore object. If it's not available within 5 seconds (see **timeoutInNanoSeconds**), then the test is treated as failed. Obviously, you can alter the values as you wish.

The rest of the tests will run either after semaphore is free or when timeout happened.

More info on semaphores can be found in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_semaphore_wait).

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself. I should not use expectation because, the setup part is not part of the testing.

I should instead use `dispatch_group`:

```
override class func setUp() {
  super.setUp()            
  let group = dispatch_group_create()
  dispatch_group_enter(group)
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) { 
      let account = MyAccount()
      WS.worker.createAccount(account, password: "test") { (success, error) in
          dispatch_group_leave(group)
      }
  }
  dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(50 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))))
}
```